# Can zip files be used to infect an Android device with malware

Tags: android, virus, zip, malware

I received a virus infected zip file and in a moment of insanity (I had just woken up) opened it in Root Explorer (my phone is rooted). I know it is infected because a) Avast detected it on my PC and B) it is obvious.

Anyway, the crux of the question. Are zip files capable of delivering a virus payload by opening them on an Android device? I've read the other posts, but none seem to deal with zip on Android.

Comment: Off-topic. Please read the android tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, possibly, but it would extremely unlikely... like getting struck by lightning while being eaten by shark unlikely.

First off, the virus is most likely intended for a Windows machine, putting it on an Android device would likely have no effect even if it would executed. Second, Android sandboxes applications, essentially putting up security walls to limit what they can do without your permission even as a root user, which would mitigate much of what malware could do without you giving it permission to do things like change system settings or send SMS messages. Third, is that by default 3rd party applications are disabled, so it if didn't come from the Play Store, it isn't going to be installed, as long as Unknown Sources is turned off in security settings (never just leave this on, if you need it, turn it on as needed and turn it off right afterwards).

Although the chances your phone could be infected are nearly zero, if you have concerns, at minimum factory reset the device, but since you are rooted I would assume you have custom recovery (and hopefully a nandoid backup), you could wipe all partitions and restore a nandroid or reflash the ROM image.

Comment: Thanks. I mainly wanted to know of reported known vulnerabilities. Good to hear that zip isn't one of them yet. The reminder about Unknown Sources was good. I do have custom recovery and backup, but I hate going through the process (it's been years). I temporarily installed Avast Mobile just to check for viruses. I'll presume nothing to worry about.

Comment: To my knowledge there is no vulnerability in ZIP or other archival file types.